# Selenium driver does not work when used as closure from lambda function

Tags: c#, selenium, lambda, closures

I've noticed that when I use a `RemoteWebDriver` from inside a lambda function but as a closure, it doesn't work, and I do this sometimes by mistake which causes bugs.

For example, this works:

```
driver.MyFunc(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("mykey")));
```

But this does not (doesn't find the element):

```
driver.MyFunc(x => driver.FindElement(By.Id("mykey")));
```

`MyFunc` is fairly simple, and calls the lambda function immediately and synchronously.

So shouldn't in theory both `driver` and `x` reference the same object?

Comment: x is an anonymous delegate... why not just driver.FindElement(By.Id("mykey")?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's key here is to have a peak at the implementation of your MyFunc method, because looking at the usage which you have provided I was able to recreate your code and can confirm that in both examples which you have provided, the driver is able to locate the element.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LambdaClosureTest
{

    public static class MyClassA
    {
        public static IWebElement MyFunc(this IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> func)
        {
            return func(driver);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();

        private static void Test()
        {
            var by = By.XPath("//*[@value = 'Google Search']");

            var elementA = Driver.MyFunc(x => x.FindElement(by));
            var elementB = Driver.MyFunc(x => Driver.FindElement(by));            
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");

            Test();
        }
    }
}
```